# Express Sessions GET vs POST requests

Tags: node.js, axios, express-session

I can access the session object data when using post method but session object data is null when using get method.How can i access session object data  using get method.
I am using express-session.

Front-end Code

For POST method

```
axios.post(url,{params:data},{withCredentials: "true"})
```

For GET method

```
axios.get(url,{params:data},{withCredentials: "true"})
```

Back-end Code
Middleware for both get and post requests.

```
router.use((req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  console.log(req);
  if (req.session && req.session.username) next();
  else res.status(401).send("Unauthorized");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`axios.get()` only takes two arguments (not three).  The first is the URL and the second is the options.  You are passing the options in the third spot which `axios.get()` does not look at.  Therefore, it never sees the `withCredentials: true` option and thus doesn't send the session cookie and thus your server doesn't know how to find the session.

So, change from this:

```
axios.get(url,{params:data},{withCredentials: "true"})
```

to this:

```
axios.get(url,{withCredentials: "true"})
```

Note, there is no data argument for `axios.get()` because a GET does not send a request body, only a POST or PUT send the body.  See the doc [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#request-method-aliases).

---

Note: This bites people regularly with `axios`.  `.post()` and `.get()` need a different number of arguments.